# Dynamically Displaying Text with TextView (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

Basically what I want to do in my Android app is use TextView to display two different pieces of text at once. So in code, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
    text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    text.setTextSize(20f);
    text.setText("Text1");
    text.setTextSize(14f);
    text.setColor(0xFF0000FF);
    text.setText("\nText2");
    ll.addView(text);
```

To clarify, I am trying to display a black "Text1" and a blue "Text2" at once using only a single TextView. Obviously this doesn't work out using the code above. I've considered using a second TextView but that seems like a waste of effort and memory to me. I'm sure the brilliant minds here can come up with the best solution to this.

Thank you very much in advance for your time and your assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options for you.

One is

[Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html)

and other is

[fromHtml (String source)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29)

So that you can get your desired output.

Comment: Simple and straight to the point. Just what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think with the current version of the code, you can see only the latest text (Text2).
If you want to have multiple look and feel for two texts, I would suggest use 2 separate TextViews. It would add more flexibility.

If you are not going to change this UI code later, then you can consider Html.toHtml() in setText() call.

Comment: As I said in my question I do NOT want to use two TextViews. That is a very wasteful and poor solution. I write RISC (mainly PPC and ARM) assembly on embedded platforms regularly which probably attributes to my strong feelings on the subject. I really don't care if my code is "ugly" so long as it's efficient (also in my opinion I would think things would be more flexible with less TextViews). But thanks for your response just the same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is with:

```
LinearLayout.addView(text);
```

You are trying to add a view to a LinearLayout, but the layout doesn't exist (in the current activity). You need to add the TextView to a Layout defined in the .xml you are using. Suppose you have a LinearLayout with id "linearlayout01" in the xml file "activity1.xml", you would do something like:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

// Create and adjust TextView text

...

LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout01);
layout.addView(text);
```

Comment: No, you completely misunderstood me. It's probably my fault; I was being generic to keep my code size down. I'll amend the question. Assume that LinearLayout does exist and then look at my question again. My problem is not that text isn't appearing, my problem is changing text dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Once a [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) is added to a [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) of which [`LinearLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) is a descendant you do not need to readd it to update its display. If you preform any changes on a view that requires it to change its display it will handle all the proper notifications about required redraws or relayouts by calling [`View#invalidate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) and [`View#requestLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout%28%29) where appropriate.

In addition, because all UI changes are handled on the same thread you do not need to worry about calling multiple methods that will update the UI. This is because of two reasons, first, the execution of the redraws will not occur until your code is finished, second, android has optimizations built in that combines multiple invalidate calls into one.

So, the only thing you need to worry about is getting a proper reference to your [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) instance and then you can call all the methods on it that you need to make it display what you wish.

Since you are creating your `View`s manually and not from xml you need to add your root `ViewGroup` to the [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) by calling [`Activity#setContentView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29).

Edit:

Then you're going to need to learn about [`SpannableString`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) and [`SpannableStringBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html). There is some very brief documentation here: [Selecting, Highlighting, or Styling Portions of Text](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext)

Comment: No, you don't understand me. It's probably my fault, I'll try to clear up the question. I want to display two different types of text in one render, not in multiple renders. With the code I posted above, only "Text2" is rendered. I want to be able to display both "Text1" and "Text2"

Comment: The info about SpannableString should be what you are looking for.

Comment: If you have any references you could provide me on that I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when do you plan to update the `textview` ? If it is on click of a button then get a reference to the `textview` and in the onClickListener() update the text, color, etc whatever you want to do.

After seeing your other comments, I think [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/text/Link.html) is what you are looking for

Comment: You do not understand my question at all. I'm sorry, it must be my fault. I'm not trying to draw text and then change it later after an Event occurs. Thats easy ;) I'm trying to render two different pieces of text at once in the same TextView.

Comment: After seeing your other comments, I think SpannableString is what you are looking for. Refer to http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/text/Link.html for an example

Comment: On the contrary you cold always use 2 textviews to achieve your task :)

Comment: Thanks for the link. If I dont get a better response from anyone soon I'll give you best answer. It may be because my roots are in C/C++ programming but SpannableString doesn't look like a particularly elegant solution either unfortunately. And as I've said since I posted my question, an additional TextView seems to be very wasteful and thus a solution I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Another thing you could do is format your string using HTML tags and then use `Html.fromHtml(String)`